# postgresql for in loop of a select statement - problem updating variable through iterations

Tags: postgresql, loops, debugging, plpgsql, increment

I've written a function to calculate exponential moving average for prices that loops through the results of a SELECT statement.  The length of the moving average is 26 days.  For the first 25 rows, the value of the EMA is null.  The 26th day is just the simple average of the first 26 values.  Any row after 26 has an EMA value of the (current row price - previous row EMA)*(2/27) + previous_row_EMA.

The loop below does this using CASE statements.  I have declared a variable "sumlong" and set it to zero.  The "sumlong" variable keeps a running summation of the first 25 rows.  The second CASE statement calculates the 26th day simple moving average.    I have also declared a variable "last_EMA26" as a temporary holder to be used in the next iteration.

The 26th row seems to calculate properly, however any row after the 26th row does not seem to hold the calculation and reuses the same value as the 26th row.  Any idea on what I am doing wrong?  Feel free to provide feedback on how I could make this code more efficient.  I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way but I'm learning.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MACD()
    RETURNS TABLE(
        _ID INTEGER,
        _CUSIP TEXT,
        _DATETIME TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
        _PCLOSE NUMERIC,
        _ROWNUM BIGINT,
        _EMAL NUMERIC
    )
AS $$
DECLARE 
    sumlong numeric := 0.00;
    sumshort numeric := 0.00;
    last_ema26 numeric := 0.00;
BEGIN
    FOR _ID, _CUSIP, _DATETIME, _PCLOSE, _ROWNUM IN
    SELECT ID, CUSIP, datetime, pclose, k
        FROM
        (SELECT ID, CUSIP, datetime, (dhist::json->>'close')::numeric AS pclose, ROW_NUMBER () OVER(w) as K 
        FROM dailyhist
        WHERE cusip = '00130H105'
        WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY CUSIP ORDER BY datetime)
        ) EMA
    LOOP
        CASE
            WHEN _ROWNUM < 26 THEN
                _EMAL := NULL;
                sumlong := sumlong + _PCLOSE;
                 RAISE NOTICE '1 counter is: %,  row: %, close: %  emal: %, lastema: %', sumlong, _ROWNUM, _PCLOSE, _EMAL, last_ema26;
            WHEN _ROWNUM = 26 THEN
                _EMAL:= (sumlong + _PCLOSE)/26;
                last_ema26 := _EMAL;
                RAISE NOTICE '2 counter is: %,  row: %, close: %  emal: %, lastema: %', sumlong, _ROWNUM, _PCLOSE, _EMAL, last_ema26;
            WHEN _ROWNUM > 26 THEN
                _EMAL = (_PCLOSE - last_ema26)*(2/27) + last_ema26;
                last_ema26 := _EMAL;
                RAISE NOTICE '3 counter is: %,  row: %, close: %  emal: %, lastema: %', sumlong, _ROWNUM, _PCLOSE, _EMAL, last_ema26;
        END CASE;
        RETURN NEXT;    
    END LOOP;
END;$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT * FROM MACD();
```

I have also included a portion of the output:

```
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 3.37517,  row: 1, close: 3.37517  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 6.79201,  row: 2, close: 3.41684  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 10.18801,  row: 3, close: 3.396  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 13.60485,  row: 4, close: 3.41684  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 17.06336,  row: 5, close: 3.45851  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 20.48020,  row: 6, close: 3.41684  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 23.77203,  row: 7, close: 3.29183  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 27.06386,  row: 8, close: 3.29183  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 30.60570,  row: 9, close: 3.54184  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 34.43922,  row: 10, close: 3.83352  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 38.33525,  row: 11, close: 3.89603  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 42.16877,  row: 12, close: 3.83352  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 46.00229,  row: 13, close: 3.83352  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 50.04416,  row: 14, close: 4.04187  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 54.29437,  row: 15, close: 4.25021  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 58.54458,  row: 16, close: 4.25021  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 62.58645,  row: 17, close: 4.04187  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 66.62832,  row: 18, close: 4.04187  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 70.48268,  row: 19, close: 3.85436  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 74.23287,  row: 20, close: 3.75019  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 77.94139,  row: 21, close: 3.70852  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 81.69158,  row: 22, close: 3.75019  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 85.48344,  row: 23, close: 3.79186  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 89.56698,  row: 24, close: 4.08354  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  1 counter is: 93.73385,  row: 25, close: 4.16687  emal: <NULL>, lastema: <NULL>
NOTICE:  2 counter is: 93.73385,  row: 26, close: 4.20854  emal: 3.7670150000000000, lastema: 3.7670150000000000
NOTICE:  3 counter is: 93.73385,  row: 27, close: 4.16687  emal: 3.7670150000000000, lastema: 3.7670150000000000
NOTICE:  3 counter is: 93.73385,  row: 28, close: 4.08354  emal: 3.7670150000000000, lastema: 3.7670150000000000
NOTICE:  3 counter is: 93.73385,  row: 29, close: 4.12521  emal: 3.7670150000000000, lastema: 3.7670150000000000
NOTICE:  3 counter is: 93.73385,  row: 30, close: 4.12521  emal: 3.7670150000000000, lastema: 3.7670150000000000
NOTICE:  3 counter is: 93.73385,  row: 31, close: 4.12521  emal: 3.7670150000000000, lastema: 3.7670150000000000
NOTICE:  3 counter is: 93.73385,  row: 32, close: 4.0627  emal: 3.7670150000000000, lastema: 3.7670150000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where is a problem, but I see one probably wrong point in a expression:

`_EMAL = (_PCLOSE - last_ema26)*(2/27) + last_ema26;`

Postgres use integer division for integer numbers by default. Probably `2/27` doesn't return what you expect

```
postgres=# select 2/27;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│        0 │
└──────────┘
 (1 row)
```

If you want to calculate some ratio, then you should not to use integer constants

```
postgres=# select 2.0/27.0;
┌────────────────────────┐
│        ?column?        │
╞════════════════════════╡
│ 0.07407407407407407407 │
└────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you Pavel, I was starting to answer my own question after realizing this but you beat to me to it.  @Timshel first response helped me narrow my focus (visually).   As a test, I changed the equation to (2.0/27.0) as you indicated above and the results changed.  I will be modifying the function to accept variable inputs (as numeric) which will be used in the equation.  Thank you.